# Tridion log files are not generating at content delivery side

Tags: 2013, logging

We are using SDL Tridion 2013 at the Content Delivery side none of the log files are generating.

It is confirmed that all required jar files (`logback-classic.jar`, `logback-core.jar`, `slf4j-api.jar`, `jcl-over-slf4j.jar`) are in the `lib` folder and `logback.xml` is also configured properly. The path of the `log` folder is correct and the app-pool has full permissions on that folder.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">
    <!-- Properties -->
    <property name="log.pattern" value="%date %-5level %logger{0} - %message%n"/>
    <property name="log.history" value="7"/>
    <property name="log.folder" value="D:/tridion/log"/>
    <property name="log.level" value="ALL"/>
    <property name="log.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>

    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="rollingTransportLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/cd_transport.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>${log.encoding}</charset>
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
    </appender>
    <appender name="rollingDeployerLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/cd_deployer.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>${log.encoding}</charset>
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
    </appender>
    <appender name="rollingMonitorLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/cd_monitor.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>${log.encoding}</charset>
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
    </appender>
    <appender name="rollingCoreLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/cd_core.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>${log.encoding}</charset>
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
    </appender>
    <appender name="rollingCacheLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/cd_cache.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>${log.encoding}</charset>
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
    </appender>
    <appender name="rollingLinkingLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/cd_link.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>${log.encoding}</charset>
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
    </appender>
    <appender name="rollingSessionPreviewLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/cd_preview.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>${log.encoding}</charset>
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
    </appender>

    <!-- Loggers -->
    <logger name="com.tridion" level="${log.level}"/>
    <logger name="com.tridion.transport" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingTransportLog"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.tridion.transport.HTTPSReceiverServlet" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingDeployerLog"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.tridion.transport.transportpackage" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingDeployerLog"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.tridion.transformer" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingDeployerLog"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.tridion.deployer" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingDeployerLog"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.tridion.tcdl" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingDeployerLog"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.tridion.event" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingDeployerLog"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.tridion.monitor" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingMonitorLog"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="Tridion.ContentDelivery" level="${log.level}" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingCoreLog"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.tridion.linking" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingLinkingLog"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.tridion.preview" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingSessionPreviewLog"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.tridion.storage.persistence.session" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingSessionPreviewLog"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="ON">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingCoreLog"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Any changes in logback.xml will not be picked up until the application restarts. Did you restarted it .

Comment: Both app-pool and website restarted after the change.

Comment: is your logfile path correct, is it at per enviroment variable TRIDION_HOME ? also Validate logback.xml file in some XML validator. i validated the xml provided by you, it seems fine.

Comment: logfile path is correct.

Comment: Try stopping the App Pool then Website. Then starting them in the order. I have faced similar issue where the logs were keep on growing. I have done above steps to stop logging.

Comment: I know you mention permissions are correct, but can you double check the app pool's _Identity_ is set to Network Service, and that this user can write to d:/tridion/log?

Comment: it was domain user and i changed to network service account and gave full control on log folder to this account and restart IIS but still i can't see any log file.

Comment: Check if by mistake there is a JAR file of name something like - `slf4j-jdkxx-x.x.x.jar` in the lib folder and ensure the path of this file is not in your CLASS PATH.
Also, do a IIS Restart (sometime you never know) :)

Comment: there is two jar file with name of slf4j first one is slf4j-api.jar and second jcl-over-slf4j.jar

Comment: 2013 does not use SLF4J anymore...

Comment: i removed slf4j-api.jar file from lib folder but still there is no log files

Comment: After removing activemq-all-5.7.0.jar from lib folder log files able to generate but the object caching is not working now.

Comment: slf4j is certainly still used in 2013, so you'll have to have all the logging jars you had back in the lib directory. You probably have a duplicate class loading issue. Check you startup logs of you application server which ones are conflicting.

Comment: How did you confirmed all the required jar files for logging as stated by you are correct?

Answer (score 4):

ON is not a valid [logback log level](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html), although IIRC, using an invalid value for level will result in DEBUG logging, so I don't think this will cause you not to see any output.

You are right to check the file permissions assigned to the application pool account. I would suggest taking this line of enquiry further using Sysinternals procmon to check for any failed file access.

You should confirm that your logback config file is, as the header says, UTF8, and that it's well-formed.

One other known cause for logging not to work is that Java is broken. I recall that Java 6 update 29 displayed exactly this behaviour, and I'm fairly sure there have been other problematic versions.

Answer (score 1):

Post is quite old but it might help someone else. The consolidated jar of activemq (activemq-all-5.14.3.jar) contains slf4j jar files as well which confilicts with the jar files already available in CD installation. For activemq add individual files of activemq from lib folder of activemq except slf4j and it will start working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the level of the root is incorrect, try:

```
<root level="OFF">
```